# need to structure my firebase realtime database

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

i need a help for structure my realtime database. i have two user types( users and councilers). when user log in then they can see counciling categories. (eg: family, education). when they select a category it redirects to the list of online councilers in that selected category but not show any user. my question is how can i manage these two types of users when log in and change online status.

```
{
  "categories" : {
    "EDUCATIONAL" : {
      "description" : "this is educational council",
      "name" : "Educational Counciling",
      "status" : true
    },
    "FAMILY" : {
      "description" : "this is family counciling",
      "name" : "Family Counciling",
      "status" : true
    }
  },
  "chats" : {
    "COUNCILER2" : {
      "jFufY3heXJgHbnuVeA9Ez1zH8ug2" : {
        "MESSAGEID1" : {
          "from" : "them",
          "text" : "Hello how are u"
        },
        "MESSAGEID2" : {
          "from" : "me",
          "text" : "hello from me"
        }
      }
    },
    "jFufY3heXJgHbnuVeA9Ez1zH8ug2" : {
      "COUNCILER2" : {
        "MESSAGEID1" : {
          "from" : "me",
          "text" : "Hello how are u"
        },
        "MESSAGEID2" : {
          "from" : "them",
          "text" : "hello from me"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "councilers" : {
    "EDUCATIONAL" : {
      "COUNCILER2" : {
        "description" : "peter test description",
        "email" : "peter123@test.com",
        "name" : "peter smith",
        "online" : true,
        "phone" : "0773453323"
      }
    },
    "FAMILY" : {
      "jFufY3heXJgHbnuVeA9Ez1zH8ug2" : {
        "description" : "test description",
        "email" : "johndoe123@test.com",
        "name" : "john smith",
        "online" : false,
        "phone" : "0770230006"
      },
      "COUNCILER3" : {
        "description" : "test description",
        "email" : "willsmith123@test.com",
        "name" : "will smith",
        "online" : true,
        "phone" : "0770230006"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "USERID1" : {
      "email" : "kalana123@test.com",
      "name" : "kalana mihiranga",
      "online" : true,
      "type" : "counciler"
    },
    "USERID2" : {
      "email" : "john123@test.com",
      "name" : "john smith",
      "online" : true,
      "type" : "user"
    },
    "jFufY3heXJgHbnuVeA9Ez1zH8ug2" : {
      "email" : "johndoe123@test.com",
      "name" : "john doe",
      "online" : true,
      "type" : "counciler"
    },
    "z5jDI0l1uBcK1RRce1SwMX3RL253" : {
      "email" : "peter123@test.com",
      "name" : "peter john",
      "online" : false,
      "type" : "user"
    }
  }
}
```

this is my structure look
but i have a problem when counciler log in how can i change online status. because i get all councilers list using councilers node and not in users node.
when counciler log in i haven't any option to identify which category is he in. so i can't change councilers node online status

Comment: As a conclusion, what the exact query you want to perform and what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when counciler log in i haven't any option to identify which category is he in. so i can't change councilers node online status

This is indeed the crux of your problem, and immediately also the crux of the solution.

When using a NoSQL database you should model your data to allow your use-cases. So if your current structure doesn't allow you to find the category for a known counciler [sic]), then you should either change the structure to allow that, or add additional data.

For example, I'd consider these options:

#### Store the councilers as a list

At first glance your JSON under `councilers` seems more deeply nested then needed. If you model it like this:

```
  "councilers" : {
      "COUNCILER2" : {
        "description" : "peter test description",
        "email" : "peter123@test.com",
        "name" : "peter smith",
        "online" : true,
        "phone" : "0773453323",
        "category": "EDUCATIONAL"
      }
      "jFufY3heXJgHbnuVeA9Ez1zH8ug2" : {
        "description" : "test description",
        "email" : "johndoe123@test.com",
        "name" : "john smith",
        "online" : false,
        "phone" : "0770230006",
        "category": "FAMILY"
      },
      "COUNCILER3" : {
        "description" : "test description",
        "email" : "willsmith123@test.com",
        "name" : "will smith",
        "online" : true,
        "phone" : "0770230006",
        "category": "FAMILY"
      }
  },
```

With the above structure, you can still get the councilers in the correct order with `firebase.database().ref("councilers").orderByChild("category")`, but now each counselor can also find their own node and update their `online` status.

#### Store an additional mapping from counciler to their category

In your current structure you can easily look up the counselors for a specific category. You can't however easily find the category for a specific counselor, which is what you need now.

One possible solution is to add that specific mapping to your database as an additional top-level list:

```
"counciler_categories": {
  "jFufY3heXJgHbnuVeA9Ez1zH8ug2": "EDUCATIONAL",
  "COUNCILER2": "FAMILY",
  "COUNCILER3": "FAMILY"
}
```

Now you can look up the category for the counselor, and then update their status under `/councilors/$category/$uid`.

#### Store the online status separate from the other data

Another option would be to separate out the status into its own top-level node, keyed by the counselor's UID:

```
"counciler_online": {
  "jFufY3heXJgHbnuVeA9Ez1zH8ug2": true,
  "COUNCILER2": false,
  "COUNCILER3": true
}
```

So with this additional structure, you'd remove the `online` property from each `/councilers/$category/$uid` node, and now the counselors can update only their status when they're online.

---

There are probably even more options than just the three common ones I outlined above, and none of these is pertinently better than the others. You'll have to pick what works for the use-cases in your app, and modify as you go along.

I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), and [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) (the latter is for a different database, but much of the advice in early episodes applies equally to other NoSQL databases).